# Send commands from lighttpd to mono application

Tags: mono, raspberry-pi, lighttpd

I'm working on a project and what I want to do, I have installed lighttpd on my raspberry pi which is running xbian and I have created asp file using to control xbmc by using some .net library.I got mono application as well to control xbmc and I want to send command or signal or message from lighttpd to the running mono application

How to do this, do i have to use any rpc, pipe etc.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could either use the `lua` or `php` plugin, parse the requests there and run your stuff accordingly.

A rather difficult alternative would be to write a plugin yourself and make that do whatever it needs to do (though this will require at least decent C skills as well as security awareness) http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/HowToWriteALighttpdPlugin

Comment: Thankz drahnr..I got another issue when i remotely accessing lighttpd in the same network the asp file is downloding rather than load in the browser but html files are loading perfectly any answers..:( thankz

Comment: I will happily answer that question if you open a separate question/thread (if you want to accept an answer, make sure to tick the swoosh left of the answer)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/fastcgi/

Separately, if files are downloading instead of being processed, then ensure that you have configured lighttpd.conf [mimetype.assign](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Mimetype_assignDetails)